# SELECT … FOR UPDATE on non-existent rows

Tags: mysql, select-for-update

i am interested about locks when "select ... for update on non-existed rows";
currently, the data in table 'test02' is as blow:

> id
>
> 1
>
> 3
>
> 8
>
> 15
>
> 20

the column id is primary key;

when i run :

session1:
start transaction;
select * from test02 where id = 7 for update;

then i open another session, and runs as fellows:

session2:
start transaction;
select * from test02 where id = 7 for update;

as i expected, session2 will waiting for gap lock (3, 8); however the two session runs normally. is there anyone can help to explain why session2 does not wait ?

but when i run following sql in session3: insert into test02(id) values (7); the session blocked, it means gap lock in session1 is used. but i don't understand why session2 can run normally.

mysql version 5.7 and 5.8 both show the same result.

Comment: but when i run following sql in session3: insert into test02(id) values (7); the session blocked, it means gap lock in session1 is used. but i don't understand where session2 can run normally.

Comment: Please edit your question to include your comment from above. The comment is pertinent to the question itself and may be overlooked by people coming to answer.

Answer (score 2):

From the [MySql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking.html#innodb-gap-locks) (version 8.0):

> It is also worth noting here that conflicting locks can be held on a
>   gap by different transactions. For example, transaction A can hold a
>   shared gap lock (gap S-lock) on a gap while transaction B holds an
>   exclusive gap lock (gap X-lock) on the same gap. The reason
>   conflicting gap locks are allowed is that if a record is purged from
>   an index, the gap locks held on the record by different transactions
>   must be merged.
>
> Gap locks in InnoDB are “purely inhibitive”, which means that their
>   only purpose is to prevent other transactions from inserting to the
>   gap. Gap locks can co-exist. A gap lock taken by one transaction does
>   not prevent another transaction from taking a gap lock on the same
>   gap. There is no difference between shared and exclusive gap locks.
>   They do not conflict with each other, and they perform the same
>   function.

In your example, session 2 does not wait for session 1 because that is just the way gap locks work in MySQL. To expect otherwise is to expect behavior that contradicts the product documentation.